# Sharepoint list search with custom styling

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-search

I want to make a list-search for sharepoint with custom styling. Could you help me a little with that? I do not know how to start with that, so I need ideas how to handle that.

I want to make this look like:

JSBin **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wohik/2/edit)**

Questions are:

1. Do I need a WebPart for that? If yes, Can I do it with 2 WebParts - 1 for search form, one for Results?
2. If I do not need webPart, how to handle search?
3. If I do not need WebPart, how to represent results in a  like in example?

Comment: What is a 'list-search'?  Are you trying to build something to search all the lists in a site or site collection?  Not really clear on what it is you want to do.

Comment: I just want to present items from a single list with a search/filter option with a custom styling/presentation form.